# go test misses coverage along the execution path

Tags: go, code-coverage

Consider a file structure like this:

```
api --
     |_ routes.go
     |_ handler.go
impl--
     |_ impl.go
     |_ impl_test.go
```

The "impl" file contains internal implementation of REST APIs for which the handlers and routes are in "handler.go" and "route.go" files respectively.

As far as packaging goes, everything under "api" folder is in the "api" package. The code in "impl.go" is in "impl" package and the code in "impl_test" package is in "impl_test" package.

```
api -------
           |_ routes
           |_ handler functions
impl-------
           |_ impl functions
impl_test--
           |_ test functions
```

The test function starts a HTTP server listening to a local open port using the routes and handlers in the "api" package and then call the APIs.

However, the coverage report shows 0% coverage for the code in the "api" package and non-zero% for "impl".

Can someone please explain why the coverage is measured for one package and not the other? And whether there is way to fix this?

Comment: Test coverage is only for one package.

Comment: Though there is [gocovmerge](https://github.com/wadey/gocovmerge) to help with that.

Comment: "Test coverage is only for one package".. How that package is chosen? Why in my case it's the "impl" and not "api"?

Comment: @AmirKeibi: the package is chosen by the one you're testing. You can only run `go test` on a single package at a time, and only one package's `_test.go` files are compiled at a time.

Comment: @JimB I understand, but the test code is neither in "impl" package nor "api". Are you saying that the test functions in "impl_test" package are treated as part of "impl" package?

Comment: @AmirKeibi: I'm not sure what you're seeing without an example and how you're invoking the command. Exactly what command are you running on which package?

Comment: @JimB I'm using "goconvey" which runs the tests in every package and spit out a HTML report.

Comment: @JimB this looks like a tooling issue. Apparently I need to explicitly tell goconvey to measure both "api" and "impl" packages with that test.

Comment: Yes, it would help if you mention that you are using a different tool to get test coverage.

Comment: Right, that's my bad. I assumed certain things about the tool which I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone using goconvey land in this question, this is an issue with the tool:

https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/issues/491